# Redux initial state in reducer not accepting new values

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, reducers

I'm running into a strange problem where the initial state in one of my reducers is not accepting new values. I've been able to add new values to this initial state easily, but for some reason now new initial state entries come back as undefined when I mapStateToProps.

```
//REDUCER
const initialState = {
    (...cutting out a bunch of state here),
    collectionSearchResults: {
    results: {},
    loading: false,
    loaded: false,
    error: ''
  },
  collectionImage: {
    image: '',
    loading: false,
    loaded: false,
    error: '',
  },
  collectionBeingEdited: {
    collectionId: '',
    loading: false,
    complete: false,
    error: '',
    test: '',
  },
  removeReport: {
    loading: false,
  }
}
```

```
//INDEX of Component
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  (...cutting out a bunch of state here)
  collectionBeingEdited: state.research.collectionBeingEdited,
  removeReport: state.research.removeReport,
  userInfo: state.account.myAccount.info,
})
```

```
//IN COMPONENT
console.log(this.props)
//result -> removeReport: undefined
```

Comment: Can you post the actual reducer as well? Not just the initialState.

Answer (score 0):

InitialState of a reducer is not a reducer. As Martin suggested, you need to post your actual reducer.

I'm willing to bet that in one of your reducer cases its not returning the rest of the state:

```
case 'something':
  return {    
    someKey: action.value
  }
```

instead of:

```
case 'something':
  return {
    ...state,
    someKey: action.value
  }
```

and thats why the property you're expecting doesnt exist.